# Symfony 2 JMS Translations Bundle

Tags: symfony, xliff

I've inherited a project which has English and Spanish translations (xliff files). I've now got to add German, and have an .xlxs file with columns to represent the translations.

The project uses the JMS Translations Bundle (https://github.com/schmittjoh/JMSTranslationBundle) but I'm unsure how to use it - the documentation is not clear. My goal is to translate the .xlxs file into xliff format so it can be used within the site.

There is a translation:extract command that comes with the bundle but it always returns an error, and besides, it doesn't look like you can target a specific file.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can use your .xlxs file with JMS Translations Bundle, you need to use the extract command to create the  new language file (German) and use the /trans_ route on your project to translate